# Parse Cloud Code Define Results

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, parse-platform, parse-server

after struggling many days I managed to retrieve the results I want from a Parse Cloud Query.

My problem is that I have two queries combouned to one, so there is need to use diffurent column to display.

I am using Ionic3/Angular 4 with Parse Server.

Here is my Parse Cloud Code

```
    Parse.Cloud.define('FriendsQuery', function (req, res) {
  const fromUserQ = new Parse.Query("Friends")
    .equalTo("toUser", req.user)
    .include('fromUser')
    .find();

  const toUserQ = new Parse.Query("Friends")
    .equalTo("fromUser", req.user)
    .include('toUser')
    .find();

  Parse.Promise.when(toUserQ, fromUserQ)
    .then((toUsers, fromUsers) =>
      res.success({
        toUsers: toUsers.map(e => e.get('toUser')),
        fromUsers: fromUsers.map(e => e.get('fromUser')),
      }))
    .catch(res.error);
});
```

meets.ts

```
import { Data } from './../../services/data';
import { localData } from './../../services/local';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Parse } from 'parse';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {User} from '../../models/User';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-meet',
  templateUrl: 'meet.html'
})
export class MeetPage {

  currentUser = Parse.User.current();
  query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  tmp =[];
  tmp2 =[];
  friends: any=[];

  initializeItems() {
  this.friends = this.localdata.tmpfriends;
  }

  retrieveFriends(){
   if (this.currentUser= Parse.User.current()) {
     console.log(this.currentUser.id)
     Parse.Cloud.run('FriendsQuery',{currentuser: this.currentUser.id}).then(
     res => {       
       console.log(res);
       this.tmp2 = res;
       this.localdata.setFriends(this.tmp2);
       this.friends = this.localdata.tmpfriends;
       console.log(this.friends);
       });            
   }
   }

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private localdata: localData, private dataService: Data) {
    this.searchControl = new FormControl;
}

showFriends: any = false;
searchControl: FormControl;
searchTerm: string = '';
searching: any = false;

filterfriends(searchTerm){ 
       return this.friends.filter((friend) => {
           return friend.fromUser.username.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
       });    
    }

ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.retrieveFriends();
  this.setFilteredItems();
  this.searchControl.valueChanges.debounceTime(700).subscribe(search => {
    this.searching = false;
    this.setFilteredItems();
     });
}

onSearchInput(){
  this.searching = true;
  }

setFilteredItems() {
  this.initializeItems();
  this.friends = this.filterfriends(this.searchTerm);
}  

onCancel(ev: any) {
  this.initializeItems();
}
}
```

meet.html

```
  <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" [formControl]="searchControl" (ionCancel)="onCancel($event)" (ionInput)="onSearchInput()">
  </ion-searchbar>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <div *ngIf="searching" class="spinner-container">
        <ion-spinner></ion-spinner>
    </div>
       <ion-item class="item-avatar item-avatar-left item-button-right common-list" >
            <ion-avatar *ngIf="friend.fromUser.objectId == currentUser.id" item-left><img style="left:0px !important;margin-top:0px !important;" [src]="friend.toUser.avatar  || '/assets/img/no-avatar.png'"/></ion-avatar>
            <ion-label *ngIf="friend.fromUser.objectId == currentUser.id">{{friend.toUser.username}}</ion-label>
            <ion-avatar *ngIf="friend.toUser.objectId == currentUser.id" item-left><img style="left:0px !important;margin-top:0px !important;" [src]="friend.fromUser.avatar  || '/assets/img/no-avatar.png'"/></ion-avatar>
            <ion-label *ngIf="friend.toUser.objectId == currentUser.id">{{friend.fromUser.username}}</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

local.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class localData {

    setFriends (friends){
        window.localStorage.friends_data = JSON.stringify(friends);
    }
    getFriends(){
       return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.friends_data || '[]');
    }

    tmpfriends = this.getFriends();
   }
```

In my table "Friends" I have two columns, "fromUser" and "toUser" and I want to display the friends of a current logged in user. So in Angular code i need both **friend.toUser.username** and **friend.fromUser.username** depending the logged in user.

When I use the first one I get only the results for the users that sent a friend request to the logged in user and the opposite.

I attach an image link to be more clear. I don`t want the results in the screen but the ones that I point with the arrows.

With the  hmtl code I managed to get this results but it is not convinienent to filter them with this one:

```
filterfriends(searchTerm){ 
return this.friends.filter((friend) => {
return friend.fromUser.username.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
});    
 }
```

Because I need to filter both friend.toUser and friend.fromUser

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNnsy.jpg)

Thank you

Comment: uh-oh: `if (this.currentUser= Parse.User.current())`  is almost certainly not doing what you think it is.  Try this instead: `if(this.currentUser.id === Parse.User.current().id)`

Comment: OOOOH, i think I understand what you want!!!  will update my answer, let's see....

Comment: Hi Arthur, yes there is no wrong with the one you mention above, but how I will display the results. The best option for me would be to to check in Cloud Code if the user is the fromUser or toUser in order to retrieve a list that finally could be used in hmtl as friend.username.I am waiting for your response!thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the whole `{ "__type": "Pointer", "className": "_User", "objectId":  req.params.currentuser }` if `toUser` and `fromUser` are already user pointers, you can just do `.equalTo("toUser", request.params.currentUser);`. Additionally, if you're making this request from a client that is logged in, you can just do `.equalTo("toUser", request.user);`

There is also a query method, `.include(<key>);` that will include the pointed to object.  So, you could do `friendQuery.include("toUser").include("fromUser");` and have that information fetched.  And, this works with dot notation, if you have some sort of additional pointer on your users, say, a ContactInfo class. You could do `query.include("toUser.contactInfo");`, and that object will be included as well.

Beyond this I'm not entirely sure what the issue you're having is. What isn't working that you want to work? It sounds like you're getting the information you wanted.

Comment: Hi Jake.I have changed the Cloud Code to: const query1 = new Parse.Query("Friends");  
    const query2 = new Parse.Query("Friends"); 
    query1.equalTo("fromUser", req.params.currentuser);
    query2.equalTo("toUser", req.params.currentuser);
    const friendquery = Parse.Query.or(query1, query2);
    friendQuery.include("toUser").include("fromUser");
    friendquery.find().then((results) => {
    res.success(results);
        })
.catch(() =>  {
  response.error("user lookup failed");
});
});  But this gives me a 500 Post Internal Server error.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the actual full code. You could always set breakpoints and step through to see exactly which line throws the internal server error, or turn on an exception breakpoint and see what the error is there. You might also have some more debugging logs than just that an error was thrown that could tell you the line / issue.  Also just the snippet of code you showed has an extra `});`, not sure if that's related or not.

Comment: Hi Jake, I have edited and added exactly the code I have now Parse Cloud Code, services and html. Now it is working but I cannot figure out the last part.

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand the question, what you want is:

1. to get back a single array of friends because you don't really care which is a fromUser and which is a toUser, you just want all the friends.
2. you want this list 'de-duped' since you may have friended and have been friended by the same user, and you don't want that in the list twice.
3. you 'may' want to filter the friends too.

It makes a lot of sense to do this in a single cloud function.

The string matching is a bit tricky.  We could use a regular expression and the [matches query](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.Query.html#methods_matches) function, but since we're matching on the user table and not on the friends table, it's tricky.  For simplicity, I just filter the results in javascript instead.

For the de-dupe, I use the lodash lib.

```
const fp = require('lodash/fp');

Parse.Cloud.define('FriendsQuery', function (req, res) {
  const fromUserQ = new Parse.Query('Friends')
    .equalTo('toUser', req.user)
    .include('fromUser')
    .find();

  const toUserQ = new Parse.Query('Friends')
    .equalTo('fromUser', req.user)
    .include('toUser')
    .find();

  return Parse.Promise.when(toUserQ, fromUserQ)
    .then((toUsers, fromUsers) => {
     const friendsWithDupes = toUsers.map(e => e.get('toUser'))
        .concat(fromUsers.map(e => e.get('fromUser')));
      // fp.uniquWith(comparator)(arrayToDeDupe);
      const friends = fp.uniqWith((x, y) => x.id === y.id)(friendsWithDupes);

      if (req.params.searchTerm) {
        const lowerSearchTerm = req.params.searchTerm.toLowerCase();
        const filteredFriends = friends.filter(
          friend => friend.get('username').toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerSearchTerm) > -1
        );
        return res.success(filteredFriends);
      }

      return res.success(friends);
    })
    .catch(e => res.error(JSON.stringify(e)));
});
```

You can call this function with or with out a search term:

`Parse.Cloud.run('FriendsQuery', { searchTerm: 'bob' })`

or

`Parse.Cloud.run('FriendsQuery')`

Comment: Hallo Arthur, i edited the question to be more clear. I added the full code of html how I display now the results and the filter function incluced in my ts file. Also i tested your cloud code with the second promise and in results if have only the id of objects. I save them locally and call them back and only then I get the wished results. But my main problem is how to show the results without to use friend.fromUser and friend.toUser in order to be able to filter them all and sort them all. For example, friend.username simply. Thank you a lot. I attach image [link](https://imgur.com/a/GPLD6)

Comment: I'm confused.  I don't understand where the filter function is used or for what purpose. I also don't understand what you mean about my cloud code and "save them locally and call them back and only then....".  The objects should be there.  did you try `results.toUser[0].get('username')`?

Comment: Thank you for you interest Arthur. I have added exactly the code parts I use to be more clear.

Comment: Hi Arthur, I tried the new Cloud Code but I have errors. in html i used <ion-label >{{friend.username}}</ion-label> to get the friends list. I attach image. It seems that in cloud code we return the username only in the filter function  not in the results [link] (https://imgur.com/a/ESfri) And about the searchterm, it is not stable as the user is typing in the searchbar different usernames

Comment: the 2. you have right is not really true, because it is not the philosophy of instagram or twitter where two users can follow each other. It is philosophy of facebook where when the one sent a request and the other one has accepted then they are friends. the second one cannot send friend request. So i think your second bullet is not valid

Comment: I attach image to be more crystal. In the first image is how the friends of a user will be displayed(ignore the button at the right). In second image, user has typed a letter to search, and in image three he continues to type to filter more. [link] (https://imgur.com/a/qgMaM)